# Keeping text on same page in OpenOffice document

Tags: openoffice.org

I am converting a bunch of html pages into an OpenOffice document (.odt), which will then be converted to a PDF.  Is there any way to get a bunch of text lines to stay on the same page (like the keep function of old formatters) (apart from turning it into a diagram)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a programming related question, but I'll take pity on you.  If you go to the Format menu, choose Paragraph, and go to the Text Flow tab, there are various options such as "do not split paragraph" and "keep with next", as well as widow and orphan settings.